# ASP.net MVC - @model update in view is not refreshed properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, model

I have a simple project where am starting to update and pass data from Controller to View, and display/refresh it in View, via the method `@Model.Name`.

The attribute Name is well updated in the controller, when click on button "France", and button "Italy", it updates in the controller. However, it only shows the update on the View (button "Display") once I refresh or reload the "definition" view page.

Searched the answer and thought it would be the `ModelState.Remove("Name");` issue but it does not seem to fix the issue.

Thank you !

My MODEL:

```
namespace Traveller.Models
{
    public class TSPMap
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TSPCity> Cities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My CONTROLLER:

```
namespace Traveller.Controllers
{
    public class DefinitionController : Controller
    {
        // Controller Variable
        static TSPMap iTSPMap = new TSPMap()
        {
            Id = 1978,
            Name = "France",
            Cities = new List<TSPCity>
            {
                new TSPCity() {Id = 1, Name = "Orleans", X=100, Y=100},
                new TSPCity() {Id = 1, Name = "Vouzon", X=200, Y=100},
                new TSPCity() {Id = 1, Name = "Paris", X=100, Y=200},
            }
        };


        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // Passing on the Data View Message
            ViewData["Message"] = "Traveller Definition page.";
            // Pass the Object Map to the View
            return View(iTSPMap);
        }

        // Action click on Button 1
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ClickButton1()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ClickButton1 method called in Controller...");
            // Change the name of the Country
            ModelState.Remove("Name");
            iTSPMap.Name = "Italy";
            return View(iTSPMap);
        }

        // Action click on Button 2
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ClickButton2()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ClickButton2 method called in Controller...");
            // Change the name of the Country
            ModelState.Remove("Name");
            iTSPMap.Name = "France";
            return View(iTSPMap);
        }
    }
}
```

My VIEW:

```
<!-- Creating a strongly type view with the model in parameters -->
@model Traveller.Models.TSPMap
<!-- main UX definition for the View Definition -->
<div>
    <h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>
</div>
<!-- Button of Activation and Test on UI -->
<div>
    <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Italy" onclick="ClickButton1()" />
    <input id="Button2" type="submit" value="France" onclick="ClickButton2()" />
    <input id="Button3" type="submit" value="Display" onclick="ClickButton3()" />
</div>
<div>
    <canvas id="mapCanvas" width="700" height="350" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</div>

<!-- Function to Display the Map in the View -->
<div>
    The map is name is: <b> @Model.Name </b>
</div>

<!-- Sript for function call on Button 1 -->
<script>
        function ClickButton1() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ClickButton1", "Definition")',
                async: true,
                 success: function (msg) {
                     ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                },
                 error: function () {
                    return "error";
                 }
        });
        }
</script>

<!-- Sript for function call on Button 2 -->
<script>
        function ClickButton2() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ClickButton2", "Definition")',
                async: true,
                 success: function (msg) {
                     ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                },
                 error: function () {
                    return "error";
                 }
        });
        }
</script>

<!-- Sript for function call on Button 3 -->
<script>
        function ClickButton3() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('mapCanvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
            context.font = '25px Arial';
            context.fillText("@Model.Name", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your `ServiceSucceeded()` function? Your returning html back to the browser, bit you never do anything with it (i.e. update the DOM). And using `ModelState.Remove("Name");` is pointless - you method does not have any parameters so nothing is added to `ModelState`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thx for your msg. I did not implement the ServiceSucceeded() method and am not sure how to use the DOM. In my case the Model is updated, but just after refresh on the page. Could oyu be  bit more specific on what you think should be done to fix this? Thx.

Comment: Your making an ajax call. The view does not magically change just because you return something from the method - you need to update the DOM in the success call back. You `msg` parameter contains the html you returned, and if you did say `$(someElement).html(msg)` then that html would be added inside `someElement`. But I do not know what your `ClickButton1.cshtml` and `ClickButton2.cshtml` views are or what you want to do with it (and it does not really make sense anyway)

Comment: What do you mean they do not have views? (of course they do - your returning them when you use `return View(iTSPMap);`. Its hard to understand what your doing here, but assuming your POSt methods are updating something in your database, and all you want to do is change the value of the `Name` in the view, if successful, then in the controller just `return Json(true);` and change the main view to `<b id="name">@Model.Name</b>` and then `success(response) { if (response) { $('#name').text('France'); } }`

Comment: And its hard to understand why you have 2 controller methods and 2 scripts (its all unnecessary and bad practice)